# How to add "Show hidden files" in right click Menu in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I would like to have this option in my menu on right click.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

And I know that I can hit Ctrl+H to show the hidden files but I want to learn so if I want to add some other options later I can use this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes‚ you can do it with this steps:

```
nano ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/hide_or_show
```

And then paste this lines to it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
OLDSTATE=$(gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden)
if [ "$OLDSTATE" == "false" ] ; then
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
else      
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden false
fi
```

And then make this file executable:

```
chmod +x  ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/hide_or_show
```

And then restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

And after this you can **right-click on any files** and **then** from scripts choose `hide_or_show`.

---

But if you want to `hide_or_show` display every where like **empty space** (not only when a files is selected):

1.Install `nautilus-actions`:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-actions
```

2.Then click on `Define a new action`.

3.From `action` tab, in the `Context-label` field, type `hide_or_show` (or any other names that you want)

4.Then check the `Display item in location context menu`.

5.From `Command` tab, in the `Path`, type `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/hide_or_show`

6.Then save the changes by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and then restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

So with this steps `hide_or_show` is always visible in `context menu > nautilus Actions action`.

Comment: I am not sure if we understand each other. I wanted to have an option in right click menu to show all hidden files like in `pcmanfm` file explorer.

Comment: @lewis4u Thanks for your reply; No this instruction do the same thing as you want . Please try it ;)

Comment: Yes, it works...but it's not as i wanted to...to be seamless like the option "Open in Terminal" in standard right click menu. You must click on some file to be able to change show_hide, it would be nice when it could work by clicking in empty space like in pcmanfm

Comment: @lewis4u yes ; but the in second method you can click on empty space . Did you tested the second one ? In the second method when you check the "Display item in location context menu" you can click on empty space.

Comment: @lewis4u Please try "nautilus-action" way.